# "Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Metadata\Property\DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory::__construct() must be an instance..."

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php, api-platform.com

While attempting to install Api-Platform (or run `composer update` on an existing Api-Platform installation, I get an error like this:

> Uncaught Error: Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Metadata\Property\DoctrineOrmPropertyMetadataFactory::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called in App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1530 ["exception" => TypeError { …}]

What can I do to be able to install Api-Platform correctly? Why is it failing on an update?

Answer (score 3):

Until a new version of Api-Platform is released (which will probably be relatively soon), you can sidestep the issue by adding this to your `composer.json`:

```
"conflict": {
    "doctrine/common": ">= 3.0",
    "doctrine/persistence": "^1.0"
}
```

(Since you are likely to already have a `conflict` key, just add the one line to your existing `conflict` rules).

A new version of`doctrine/common` was released, and the current version of Api-Platform is not compatible with it.

Sometime in the near future you'll be able to remove that line, once a new version of Api-Platform is released.

[Here](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3683) is an issue where you can keep an eye on the discussion, and hopefully track when the issue is resolved at this bundle's level.

---

This is no longer necessary. You can update to the latest Doctrine packages with the latest Api-Platform package, and every works fine together.